# How To Disable zoom From safari browser using jquery / javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using below code for disable zoom from all browser. ->

```js
<script>
 $(window).keydown(function(event) 
  {
   if((event.keyCode == 107 && event.ctrlKey == true) || (event.keyCode == 109 && event.ctrlKey == true))
   {
    event.preventDefault(); 
   }

   $(window).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event) 
   {
    if(event.ctrlKey == true)
    {
     event.preventDefault(); 
    }
   });
  });
 </script>
```

But in safari browser zoom is still enable so how to fixed it in safari please suggest.

Comment: Are you sure you need to disable the zoom in a webpage? Your users will be angry... In my case, if I found a website that makes this, I will quitting hurry up

Comment: Yes,I am Sure When i Press ctrl + Mouse Scroll Its Zooming Please Suggest Me How To Disable and fixed it in Sufari

Comment: `mousewheel` is not an standard event. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousewheel And try with `return false`  instead of `preventDefault`. However you must to search in google or here in stackoverflow, because there are zillions of articles with this issue.